# Null pointer exception only when downloading from google play

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting this null pointer exception in my android app:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at a.a.a.a.l.b(SourceFile:1)
    at a.a.a.b.c$a.c(SourceFile:9)
    at a.a.a.b.c.b(SourceFile:29)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$f.a(SourceFile:14)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$u.a(SourceFile:162)
```

I have an android app with three fragments and a bottom bar that shows some information from a firebase database. The app is already in google play and the prelaunch report is showing the exception.
I check my code and add an if before calling the method equals in all string objects, calling the method only if the object is not null. The worst part is that when I check on my device (with the app installed from an android studio) to be able to debug, the app does not crash. But if I download the app from google play, it crashes.

Below are the log and the other files

```
public class SpecialsFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {


    private SpecialsViewModel specialsViewModel;
    private ImageView mExpandedImage;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    private ExpandableSpecialsAdapter specialsAdapter;
    private RecyclerView specialsRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    public View onCreateView( @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                              ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        ((Main2Activity)getActivity()).fragmentState = MainActivityNavigationState.ShowingSpecials;

        specialsViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SpecialsViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_specials, container, false);

        refreshLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);
        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mExpandedImage = ((Main2Activity)getActivity()).getExpandedImage();

        specialsRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.specials_recyclerview);
        specialsAdapter = new ExpandableSpecialsAdapter(getContext(), mExpandedImage);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

        specialsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        specialsRecyclerView.setAdapter(specialsAdapter);

        return root;
    }

    private Specials getSpecial( QueryDocumentSnapshot document ) {
        String name = document.get("name").toString();
        String  where = document.get("where").toString();
        String fromDay = document.get("from_day").toString();
        String toDay = document.get("to_day").toString();
        String fromTime = document.get("from_hour").toString();
        String toTime = document.get("to_hour").toString();
        String pic = document.get("picture").toString();
        String description = document.get("description").toString();
        return new Specials(name, where, fromDay, toDay, fromTime, toTime, pic, description);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated( @NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        onRefresh();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        specialsViewModel.getAllSpecials().observe(this, new Observer<List<ListItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged( List<ListItem> listItems ) {
                if (listItems.size()>0)
                    specialsAdapter.setData(listItems);
                else {

                    specialsAdapter.setData(new ArrayList<ListItem>());
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sorry, we don't have any specials at the moment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }

        });
    }

}
```

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: com.rp.myrestaurants, PID: 14148
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at a.a.a.a.l.b(SourceFile:1)
    at a.a.a.b.c$a.c(SourceFile:9)
    at a.a.a.b.c.b(SourceFile:29)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$f.a(SourceFile:14)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$u.a(SourceFile:162)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$c.a(SourceFile:10)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(SourceFile:107)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(SourceFile:94)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(SourceFile:126)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.f(SourceFile:8)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.d(SourceFile:9)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(SourceFile:2)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5441)
    at androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:11)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5441)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5441)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5441)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:12)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5441)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5441)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:13)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5441)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5441)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5441)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16651)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5441)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1943)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:169)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:161)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiCont
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"



android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rp.myrestaurants"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
            // your project's release build type.
            minifyEnabled true
            // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
            // Android Gradle plugin.
            shrinkResources true
        }

    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = "1.8"
        sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '29.0.2'


}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'





    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'

    //crahslitics dependecy
    // (Recommended) Add Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    // Add dependency


    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'


    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    def nav_version = "2.1.0-rc01"

    // Java
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    implementation "com.ablanco.zoomy:zoomy:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'


    // Extensions = ViewModel + LiveDat



    implementation group: 'androidx.room', name: 'room-runtime', version: '2.1.0'
    //implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.1.0"
    annotationProcessor group: 'androidx.room', name: 'room-compiler', version: '2.1.0'

    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:2.1.0"


    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Where are you checking that the value isn't null?

Comment: please add `build.gradle(Module:app)`

Comment: build.gradle added to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole night of searching and studing the code, and thanks to the question of @Ehsan msz, I found the problem.
It seems like the optimization of the code delete some important code.

I just remove this from gradle and now everything is fine.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
            // your project's release build type.
            minifyEnabled true
            // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
            // Android Gradle plugin.
            shrinkResources true
        }

    }
```

Thanks you all.

Comment: You delete everything inside buildTypes?

Comment: Yes. In my case, the problem is that when I enabled minify and the option to shrink resources, because it is automatic it was removing some resources that I need for certain functionalities. There is a way to be more specific on what you don't want to be removed. In my case, this was the best solution because the app  size is small. It is more useful for apps that have a big size.